# Apply conditions in gulp.dest

Tags: gulp, gulp-uglify

I have a gulp task which gets the html file, finds the scripts inside it, minifies them, applies revisions and outputs everything in the assets folder:

`templates/index.html`

```
<!-- build:js js/app.js -->
<script src="lib/js/a.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/b.js"></script>
<!--endbuild -->
```

`gulpfile.js`

```
var useref = require('gulp-useref'),
filter = require('gulp-filter'),
uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
rev = require('gulp-rev'),
revReplace = require('gulp-rev-replace');


gulp.task('build',function() {

var assets = useref.assets({searchPath: './'}),
    jsapp = filter('**/app.js'),

return gulp
        .src(gulp.src('templates/index_src.html'))
        // collect all assets from source file by the means of useref
        .pipe(assets)
        //build js/app.js
        .pipe(jsapp)
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(jsapp.restore())
         // Take inventory of the file names for future rev numbers
        .pipe(rev())
        // Apply the concat and file replacement with useref
        .pipe(assets.restore())
        .pipe(useref())
        // Replace the file names in the html with rev numbers
        .pipe(revReplace())
        // output files
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

This works fine but outputs everything (js/app.js and index.html) to the root directory (./);

Is there are any way to apply a condition inside the `gulp.dest` and output js/app.js to the root folder of the project but output index.html to a different location (e.g. `./templates_cache`)?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filter

Comment: I already use gulp-filter (see my code above). How can I modify my code so I can save the stuff to different locations? Can you provide an example?

Comment: There are examples in the link above; that's why I linked to it. Put a `.pipe(gulp.dest('.......'))` before you restore the stream back to its unfiltered state.

Answer (score 0):

Also add a filter for your html files, to be able to output only those files to a different folder:

```
var htmlFilter = filter('**/*.html')
```

Change your output to:

```
// output for js files
.pipe(jsapp)
.pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
.pipe(jsapp.restore())

// output for html files
.pipe(htmlFilter)
.pipe(gulp.dest('./templates_cache'));
```